# Elementary math proof

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $\sigma$ : $\mathbb{Z}_{11} \to \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ be given by $\sigma([a]) = [5a + 3]$. Prove that $\sigma$ is bijective.

Approach It has to be one to one and onto so

It is one to one if $\sigma([a1])=\sigma([a2])$

$[5a1+3]=[5a2+3]$

$[5a1]=[5a2]$

$[a1]=[a2]$

Does this approach work?. How to show that it's onto
it would be like $\sigma([y-3/5])=[5(y-3)/5+3]$.

Comment: Please see [How can I format mathematics here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) together with [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and format your question properly.

Comment: If a map from a finite set to itself is one-one, then it is guaranteed to be onto.

Comment: Any reason for the switch from $\sigma$ to $G$?

Comment: No, I do not like your proof.  How do you go from $[5a1+3]=[5a2+3]$ to $[5a1]=[5a2]$?  Instead of just stating something out of the blue, you should use the definition of the equivalence classes $[5a1+3]$ and $[5a2+3]$.

Comment: When you prove the map is one-to-one, you're done (pigeonhole principle).

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic fact of  discrete mathematics that for a finite set $A$ an injective map $f:\>A\to A$ is automatically bijective. Therefore it is sufficient to prove injectivity of your $\sigma$. Now $\sigma([a])=\sigma([b])$ can be unpacked to $$(5a+3)=(5b+3 )\  + 11k, \qquad k\in{\mathbb Z}\ .$$
This implies $11\> |\> 5(a-b)$, hence $11\> |\> (a-b)$. The latter is saying that $[a]=[b]$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\sigma$ is surjective (or "*onto*"), we have to show that $\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X \text{ such that } y = \sigma(x)$ (see. [this Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection)). Here $Y = Z_{11} = X$. Because there is no further information about $Z_{11}$ this might not be fulfilled. Example: $Z_{11} = \{ 8 \}$ this would mean that for $y = 8 \in Y = \{ 8 \}$ there must exist an element $x \in  X= \{ 8 \}$ such that $8 = 5x + 3$. But the $x$ solving this equation is $1$ which is not in $ X= \{ 8 \}$.

Comment: Presumably by $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ the OP means $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$.